# I need to group a result set

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server2014. I have a problem

```
select *
     from (
        select [DataTime] datatime,[Temperature] temperature,[Humidity] humidity, 
        b.[serialnumber] serialnumber, Row_Number() OVER(ORDER BY a.datatime) rownum 
        from [dbo].[datalog] a,[report_devicelist] b where a.deviceno = b.deviceno and b.report_no='201906140013yEcD'
        and a.datatime between '2019-04-09 15:05:00' and '2019-04-09 16:20:52'
    ) as t where rownum between 1 and 50
```

```
time    temperature humidity    serialnumber    rownum
2019-04-09 15:05:01 268 0   ch4 1
2019-04-09 15:05:01 272 0   ch5 2
2019-04-09 15:05:01 266 0   ch6 3
2019-04-09 15:05:01 264 0   ch7 4
2019-04-09 15:05:01 263 0   ch8 5
2019-04-09 15:06:01 253 0   ch3 15
2019-04-09 15:06:01 245 0   ch2 16
2019-04-09 15:06:01 257 0   ch1 17
2019-04-09 15:06:01 272 0   ch14    18
2019-04-09 15:06:01 250 0   ch13    19
2019-04-09 15:06:01 254 0   ch12    20
2019-04-09 15:06:01 263 0   ch11    21
2019-04-09 15:06:01 256 0   ch10    22



time    ch1 ch2 ch3 ch4 ch5 ch6 ch7 ch8 ch9
2019/03/05 11:41:01 16.9    15.3    17.2    17.1    15.2    16.9    17.4    16.1    17.1 
2019/03/05 11:42:01 16.5    15.4    16.8    16.6    14.8    16.7    17.0    15.9    16.3 
2019/03/05 11:43:01 16.3    15.5    16.6    16.2    14.5    16.5    16.6    15.9    15.9 
2019/03/05 11:44:01 16.4    15.3    16.7    15.9    14.4    16.9    16.3    16.1    15.6 
2019/03/05 11:45:01 16.8    15.2    16.7    15.7    14.3    16.7    16.0    16.6    15.4 
2019/03/05 11:46:01 16.6    15.1    16.9    15.4    14.2    16.5    15.8    16.7    15.3 
2019/03/05 11:47:01 16.6    15.2    17.4    15.4    14.3    17.7    15.9    16.6    15.3 
2019/03/05 11:48:01 16.2    15.0    17.1    15.4    14.2    17.5    15.8    16.4    15.3 
2019/03/05 11:49:01 15.8    14.5    16.8    15.2    14.1    17.1    15.5    16.1    15.1 
2019/03/05 11:50:01 15.2    13.7    16.4    14.8    13.9    16.4    14.9    15.5    14.8 
2019/03/05 11:51:01 14.6    12.7    15.8    14.3    13.5    15.6    14.2    14.8    14.2
```

I need to group the following results based on the event.
That is, all the serial number temperatures need to be listed at each time point.I tried to use datatime group by.But the other columns are not in the aggregate function.

Comment: I also tried the inversion of the ranks. But there is a problem, I am not sure how many serialnumber there are. They are not a fixed value

Comment: You should prepare some mockup data, so that people can just copy paste and find a solution for you

Comment: And also show the desired output

Comment: It seems like you want a pivot query - are you trying to turn a vertical list of results into a horizontal one? e.g. 10 rows with the same time and different measurements becaomse 1 row of 11 columns - the time and 10 columns of the different 10 measurements?

Comment: I tried it.But the serialnumber is uncertain.
May from ch1 to ch10.may from ch1 to ch49

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to utilize `pivot` table as:

```
select top 50 datatime,[ch1], [ch2], [ch3], [ch4], [ch5], [ch6], [ch7], [ch8], [ch9]
from
    (select 
           [DataTime] datatime,[Temperature] temperature 
            b.[serialnumber] serialnumber
    from [dbo].[datalog] a,[report_devicelist] b where a.deviceno = b.deviceno and b.report_no='201906140013yEcD'
         and a.datatime between '2019-04-09 15:05:00' and '2019-04-09 16:20:52'
    ) AS SourceTable
    PIVOT  
    (  
    AVG(temperature) 
    FOR serialnumber IN ([ch1], [ch2], [ch3], [ch4], [ch5], [ch6], [ch7], [ch8], [ch9])  
    ) AS PivotTable
Order by datatime;
```

and limit the number of queries to `top 50` that sorted by `[datatime]`.

Comment: thanks.
If you look at the previous comments, you will know. I have already used it pivot.
But the serialnumber is uncertain. May from ch1 to ch10.may from ch1 to ch49.

Comment: If it is important for you to have at any time the temperature of each serial number , then it is compulsory to include titles that can be considered as a serial number . So it returns for those times when the temperature is recorded on that serial number. However, on the pivot tables, you need to specify which columns you will eventually have

Comment: I think You need to put some sample data together to test.